# Define Eventhandler with EventArgs and Event to work in multiple classes

Tags: c#, events, event-handling, eventargs

I have my custom `EventArgs` in a separate class file that I can reference it later from different classes:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace SplitView
{
    public class RowSelectedEventArgs:EventArgs {
        public Patient selectedRow { get; set; }

        public RowSelectedEventArgs(Patient selectedRow) : base(){
            this.selectedRow = selectedRow;
        }
    }
}
```

In my *MasterViewController* I defined my event

```
public event EventHandler<RowSelectedEventArgs> RowClicked;
```

In *DataSource* which is in *MasterViewController* I can raise the event:

```
if (this.controller.RowClicked != null) {
    this.controller.RowClicked (this, new RowSelectedEventArgs (this.controller.list [indexPath.Row]));
}
```

As you can see I have a field (*controller*) in my *DataSource* with which I reference the event. Now I have a *SearchSource* with the same concept (also field called *controller*). Now in *SearchSource* I want to raise the event:

```
if (this.controller.RowClicked != null) {
    this.controller.RowClicked (this, new RowSelectedEventArgs (this.list [indexPath.Row]));
}
```

But I get

> The event 'SplitView.MasterViewController.RowClicked' can only appear
>   on the left hand side of += or -= when used outside of the type
>   'SplitView.MasterViewController'

The only difference is that *SearchSource* is not part of the class *MasterViewController* (as it is with *DataSource*). But the event is `public` so it should work?

How can I raise the same event from different classes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't directly raise an event outside of the type, which defines this event.
All you can do, is a method, which will raise event from outside:

```
public sealed class MyClass
{
    // this should be called from inside
    private void OnSomeEvent()
    {
        var handler = SomeEvent;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        }
    }

    // this should be called from outside
    public void RaiseSomeEvent()
    {
        OnSomeEvent(); 
    }

    public event EventHandler SomeEvent;

    // other code here...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is the field conroller in SearchSource also fo type MasterViewController?
It seems that it is a different type.